# How can I plot ROC curve and calculate AUC, determine cutoff value?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, roc

To evaluate diagnostic performance, I want to plot ROC curve, calculate AUC, and determine cutoff value

I have concentration of some protein, and actual disease diagnosis result (true of false)

I found some references, but I think they are optimized for machine learning.

And I’m not python expert. I can't figure out how to replace the test data with my own.

Here is some references and my sample data.

Could you please help me?

```
Sample  Value   Real
1   74.9    T
2   64.22   T
3   45.11   T
4   12.01   F
5   61.43   T
6   96  T
7   74.22   T
8   79.9    T
9   5.18    T
10  60.11   T
11  14.96   F
12  26.01   F
13  26.3    F
```

Comment: Some example plots
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekBus.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4HbP.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhQcj.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdVI8.png

Comment: And references
https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.statology.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2021%2F04%2FrocPython2.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.statology.org%2Fplot-roc-curve-python%2F&tbnid=Q5BrZ17y09ik3M&vet=12ahUKEwjz-OuO16j2AhXVNaYKHZGDASwQMygDegQIARAh..i&docid=pMm6etVsfgm01M&w=856&h=582&q=roc%20diagnostic%20concentration%20tutorial%20jupyter&ved=2ahUKEwjz-OuO16j2AhXVNaYKHZGDASwQMygDegQIARAh 
https://www.datatechnotes.com/2019/11/how-to-create-roc-curve-in-python.html
https://bookdown.org/cardiomoon/roc/intro.html

Comment: This isn't a Python specific question, as in your misunderstanding isn't with Python, but with the statistical modeling process. What you're looking to do is run a logistic regression (LR) model, and then evaluate it with ROC and AUC. Cutoff/threshold in LR is arbitrary, what you're looking to do is determine and adjust class weight.